# How do I configure additional authentication options in IdentityServer 4?

Tags: asp.net-identity, identityserver4, openid-connect

I have an existing system that uses Identity Server 4, OpenIDConnect's implicit code flow, and AspNetCore Identity with a MongoDbStore. Users currently register/login with a username and password. I am trying to allow users to login with IDs and PINS that will be validated against a separate Mongo collection. I need help determining the best approach for this functionality. Is this essentially multi-tenant using the profile service? Do I configure a new client? Can I conditionally override validation?

Here is the `ConfigureServices` method in my `Startup.cs`:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>(config => { config.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true; })
                .AddMongoDbStores<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, Guid>
                (
                    Configuration.GetSection("MongoDb:ConnectionString").Value,
                    Configuration.GetSection("MongoDb:Database").Value
                )
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            services.AddServices();
            services.AddSettings(Configuration);

            services.Configure<IdentityConfig>(Configuration.GetSection("IdentityConfig"));
            services.AddScoped<IdentityConfig>(sp => sp.GetService<IOptionsSnapshot<IdentityConfig>>().Value);

            services.AddMvc();
            services.AddSession();

            IdentityConfig identityConfig = Configuration.GetSection("IdentityConfig").Get<IdentityConfig>();

            services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(identityConfig.PublicOrigin))
                {
                    options.PublicOrigin = identityConfig.PublicOrigin;
                }

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(identityConfig.IssuerUri))
                {
                    options.IssuerUri = identityConfig.IssuerUri;
                }
            })
                .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
                .AddInMemoryPersistedGrants()
                .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(GetIdentityResource(identityConfig.IdentityResources))
                .AddInMemoryApiResources(GetAPIResources(identityConfig.ApiResources))
                .AddInMemoryClients(GetClients(identityConfig.Clients))
                .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The login process is a seperate process that is not related to clients or resources. The resulting token is therefor not influenced by the way a user logs in. So there is no need to change clients, resources or use / change the ProfileService.

What I would do is, use the existing framework for configuration, etc and create your own store for user validation. Because it doesn't matter how you validate the user.

The 'default' code (from `Account/Login`) is something like this:

```
await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(username, password, rememberLogin, true);
// If valid
var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(username);
```

But since you are not validating a password, using an alternative store, you can replace this with something like this:

```
// Lookup the user first and then validate the pin
var mUser = await _mongoDbStore.FindUserByIdAsync(id);
// Your validation, e.g. by mUser or id
var isValid = await _mongoDbStore.ValidatePinAsync(id, pin);
if (isValid)
{
    // Look up the user from the Identity store,
    // using the username from the MongoDbStore.
    var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(mUser.Username);

    // Sign in the user
    await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, rememberLogin);

}
```

Please note that this is client independent, since IdentityServer implements single sign-on (SSO). This means that the user doesn't have to login when the user is already authenticated initiated by another client.

If you want to set this per client, you need to disable SSO (prompt = login). Then you can implement different login approaches per client.

If you want to enable this per user, then you may want to implement this as two-factor authentication (2FA): AspNetUser.TwoFactorEnabled. First ask for the Id and validate the pin in the second step.